# progressBar only updating last called value

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I am trying to update the progress bar as per the time taken by a function(which I wrote here in numerical terms) to be processed.But it only shows the last called value.

```
public static void updateProgress(int x)
    {
        Program.f.progressBar1.Visible = true;
        Program.f.progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        Program.f.progressBar1.Value +=x;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

above fn is used to update the progress bar.

```
public static Form1 f;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        f = new Form1();
        f.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        f.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        f.progressBar1.Value = 0;
        updateProgress(25);     //fn1
        updateProgress(50);     //fn2
        Application.Run(f);
        }
```

The progressBar directly shows 75% progress.
Thanks

Comment: Remove `updateProgress()` calls before displaying the form (it's displayed when you call `Application.Run()`) and rather do it after it is displayed. E.g. add a button to the form in `Click` event handler of which call `updateProgress(25)`. Normally progress is shown for something what runs in parallel (e.g. another thread), you can create one by using [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: it won't show any progress if called after Application.Run()

Comment: Thread.Sleep blocks the exection on the current thread. Try using a background worker or async/await pattern if possible

Comment: and I don't want to add a button either. I want to close it after 100% progress.

Comment: Also you are running the entire process before the form even starts.

Comment: If called after starting the form progress is still 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong**: you are doing something before form is displayed:

```
static void Main()
{
    f = new Form1(); // form instance is created
    f.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    f.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    f.progressBar1.Value = 0;
    updateProgress(25); // you do something and change property
    updateProgress(50); // you do something and change property
    Application.Run(f); // here form is displayed and you see the most recent change
}
```

**Correct**: to simulate work, which run in background (while form is displayed) you can do something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    f = new Form1(); // form instance is created
    f.progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    f.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    f.progressBar1.Value = 0;
    // create and start task running in parallel
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait long enough until form is displayed
        updateProgress(25);
        updateProgress(50);
    });
    Application.Run(f);
}

public static void updateProgress(int x)
{
    // Invoke is required because we run it in another thread
    f.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
    {
        Program.f.progressBar1.Visible = true;
        Program.f.progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        Program.f.progressBar1.Value +=x;
    }));
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate work
}
```